# Массивы не расширяются обычным способом в TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Наткнулся на такой пример:

```
class MyArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    logCount() {
        console.log("Count: " + this.length)
    }
}

var myArray = new MyArray<string>();
myArray.logCount();
```

Этот пример вернет ошибку, что метод logCount не найден.

И далее предлагается "правильное" решение:

```
class MyArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    constructor(items?: Array<T>) {
        super(...items);
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, Object.create(MyArray.prototype));
    }
    logCount() {
        console.log("Count: " + this.length)
    }
}
```

Это просчет TS? Ведь авторы могли:

1. Сгенерировать такой код автоматически
2. Выдать предупреждение
3. Запретить вообще наследование от массива на уровне языка

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-work

Comment: @overthesanity т.е это фича компиляции под старый стандарт?